# Unity set PlayerPrefs data regularly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am using PlayerPerfabs to store player data like which level the player has unlocked and the point has got during the game, and I want the PlayerPerfabs data updated regularly(like per 5 seconds) during playing, so I made a class called ApplicationModel to hold the global data like points player get the level info etc..

```
public ApplicationModel: MonoBehaviour{
    public static int point {get;set;}

    //try to load the PlayerPerfabs when start game.
    static ApplicationModel(){
        if(PlayerPerfabs.HasKey("point")){
            point = PlayerPerfabs.GetInt("point");
        }else{
            point = 0;
        }

    }

    //coroutine to set the data to PlayerPerfabs
    IEnumerator Save()
    {
        while (true)
       {
          Debug.Log("setting playerperfab ....");
          yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
          ApplicationModel.RestorePerfab();
       }
    }

    public static void RestorePerfab(){
         PlayerPerfabs.SetInt("point", point);
    }
    private void Start(){
      StartCoroutine(Save());
    }

}
```

But the coroutine was never executed according to the console log (cause the log was never printed).

Maybe because I didn't attach this script to a gameobject but once I attach this to a game object, then when the scene changed or that gameobject is destroyed, the regularly saving will ended, right? So how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `GameObject` and then attach this script to it if you want it to work. If you're changing scenes and want it to continue working you could call `DontDestroyOnLoad` on that `GameObject` and it won't get destroyed when you switch scenes.

Comment: I think it would be better to use a singleton. As data link deos not need to be duplicated.